# How to run drush tests from the command line?

Tags: 7, drush

I installed drush via composer, initially drush 8 was installed.

I then try to run tests via drush test-run command,unfortunately I get the following output indicating the command is not found.

> (16:38 vagrant@devbox .composer) > drush test-run help The drush
>   command 'test-run help' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear
>   drush` to clear the       [error]

Installing version 7 via composer gives same output. Clearing the drush cache did not help, am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [test-run command was removed from Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1362); the recommendation now is to simply run the `scripts/run-tests.sh` script in Drupal folder directly.

See: [Running tests through command-line](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/testing/running-tests-through-command-line).

Comment: Instructions: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/testing/running-tests-through-command-line

Comment: this link redirects to https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/running-tests-through-command-line-with-run-testssh, I can't find documentation for Drupal 7

Answer (score 3):

The exact command to run the test from drupal root is :

```
php scripts/run-test.sh module_name
```

Where module name may be Profile for example or your custom module name.
Similarly you can run particular test case from a particular module as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in the composer directory. You need to be in the Drupal root of your site to run most commands.

Also you'll need the testing module enabled. Is it Simpletest?

Comment: Yes it is simpletest and will be shown as Testing in drupal UI.